# nested for loops, 2nd for loop based off of the length of the 1st

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, compare, nested-loops

for my assignment I need to loop through list of words (5757 total) and compare all words with easy other.

The words are sorted and I make an array with them all, that's not important, checking words isn't an issue for me.
Here's where my issue is.

```
for(int i= 0; i< 5757; i++){
        for(int j = i; j < i+10; j++){
```

I want the 2nd for loop to go from CURRENT location in the first for loop (hence temp) TO i+10
but as you can tell obviously, my issue is that temp ends at 5757 but i checks for temp +10...
which breaks everything.
I'm sorry I'm just really bad at wording this question and I can't figure out how to word this better or how to find answer to this question.

Basically, what I want is this

> Check word at position i with 10 following words (hence the 2nd for loop, j = i to i+10.
>     so like this i check words
>     arrayOfWords[i] to arrayOfWords[i+10]

like this i get to check 10 following words for every word and then do the check.

But again, as I said, the issue comes with it going out of bounds by going to i+10...
I've no idea how to do this better, or how to word this question better.
Pleas help.
Thank you in advance for taking your time to answer my horribly worded question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find the minimum of `Word Length`(i.e. **5757**)  & `i+10` in second Loop.

```
int maxWordLen = 5757;
for(int i = 0; i < maxWordLen ; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < min(maxWordLen, i + 10) ; j++){
        . . .
    }
}
```